# jQuery iterate over sortable tree structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, iteration, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm creating a dynamic navigation tree structure using jQuery UI sortables and nested sortable.

When the items are relocated, I'm trying to iterate over each branch and add a button at the bottom if it doesn't have one.

I'm having some problems with creating a recursive function to iterate over each branch. If I use `.children('.ui-menu-item-branch')`, it doesn't seem to find the sub-branches. If I use `.find('> .ui-menu-item-branch')`, it finds all sub-branches.

How should I amend the code to iterate over each branch only once?

```js
function addButton (el, index) {
 var tpl = '<li class="add-menu-item"><button class="ui-button button-add-item" type="button">Add menu item</button></li>';

 var branches = $(el).children('.ui-menu-item-branch');
 console.log ('branches: ' + index);
 console.log (branches);
 
 $.each(branches, function(i, el) {
  console.log ('element: ' + index);
  console.log (el);  
  index++;
  addButton (el, index); 
 });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.sortable').nestedSortable({
  handle: '.ui-menu-handle',
  placeholder: 'ui-menu-placeholder',
  items: 'li:not(.add-menu-item)',
  toleranceElement: '> div',
  branchClass: 'ui-menu-item-branch',
  leafClass: 'ui-menu-item-leaf',
  collapsedClass: 'ui-menu-item-collapsed',
  expandedClass: 'ui-menu-item-expanded',
  errorClass: 'ui-menu-item-invalid',
  isTree: true,
  distance:0,
  maxLevels: 3,
  isAllowed: function (placeholder, placeholderParent, currentItem) {
   if (placeholder.prev().hasClass('add-menu-item')) {
    return false;
   }
   if (placeholderParent && placeholderParent.hasClass('add-menu-item')) {
    return false;
   }
   return true;
  },
  relocate: function (event, currentItem) {
   var target = $(event.target);
   addButton (target, 0);  
  }
 });
  
  $('.sortable').on('click', '.button-add-item', function (e) {
  var el = $(this);
  var tpl = '<li class="ui-menu-item"><div class="ui-stack ui-stack-wrap ui-stack-align-center sortable-menu-item"><div class="ui-menu-handle ui-sortable-handle"></div><div class="ui-menu-item-title">Sub Content 2</div></div></li>';
  $(tpl).insertBefore(el);
 });
});
```

```css
body {
margin: 0;
}
.ui-stack {
 display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    margin-top: -1.6rem;
    margin-left: -1.6rem;
}
.ui-stack>* {
 -webkit-box-flex: 0;
 -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
 -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
 flex: 0 0 auto;
 margin-top: 1.6rem;
 margin-left: 1.6rem;
}
.ui-stack-wrap {
 -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.ui-stack-center {
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.ui-stack-align-center {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.ui-stack-vertical {
 -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
 -webkit-box-direction: normal;
 -webkit-flex-direction: column;
 -ms-flex-direction: column;
 flex-direction: column;
}
.ui-stack-item {
    min-width: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.ui-stack-item-fill {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
.ui-card-section.ui-navigation {
 padding: 0;
 margin-top: 20px;
}

.ui-navigation ol {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
}
.ui-navigation li {
 padding: 0;
}

.ui-navigation ol ol {
 padding-left: 30px;
}

.ui-navigation ol ol .sortable-menu-item, .ui-navigation ol ol .button-add-item {
 border-left: 1px solid #dfe3e8;
}
.sortable-menu-item {
 padding: 10px;
 background: white;
 border-top: 1px solid #dfe3e8;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #dfe3e8;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #dfe3e8;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-left: 0;
 line-height: 30px;
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.ui-menu-handle {
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 background-color: #5c6ac4;
 border-radius: 50%;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin: 0;
}
.ui-menu-placeholder {
 position: relative;
 background-color: #5c6ac4;
 height: 2px;
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: -1px;
 margin-bottom: -1px;
}
.ui-menu-placeholder:before {
 position: absolute;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #5c6ac4;
    top: -4px;
    left: -9px;
    content: "";
}
.ui-menu-placeholder.ui-menu-item-invalid, .ui-menu-placeholder.ui-menu-item-invalid:before {
 background-color: #ddd;
 border-color: #bbb;
}

.ui-menu-item-title {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0 0.8rem;
}
.button-add-item {
 width: 100%;
 background: #f4f5fa;
    color: #5c6ac4;
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-transition: none;
    transition: none;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #dfe3e8;
    border-color: #dfe3e8;
    border-radius: 0;
    line-height: 34px;
 padding: 10px 15px;
}
.button-add-item:hover {
 border-color: #5c6ac4;
    background: #5c6ac4;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nestedSortable/2.0.0/jquery.mjs.nestedSortable.js"></script>
<head>
<body>
<div class="ui-navigation">
<ol class="sortable">
  <li class="ui-menu-item" data-menu-item='{"title":"Content 1"}'>
    <div class="ui-stack ui-stack-wrap ui-stack-align-center sortable-menu-item">
      <div class="ui-menu-handle"></div>
      <div class="ui-menu-item-title">Content 1</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item" data-menu-item='{"title":"Content 2"}'>
    <div class="ui-stack ui-stack-wrap ui-stack-align-center sortable-menu-item">
      <div class="ui-menu-handle"></div>
      <div class="ui-menu-item-title">Content 2</div>
    </div>
    <ol>
      <li class="ui-menu-item" data-menu-item='{"title":"Sub Content 1"}'>
        <div class="ui-stack ui-stack-wrap ui-stack-align-center sortable-menu-item">
          <div class="ui-menu-handle"></div>
          <div class="ui-menu-item-title">Sub Content 1</div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="ui-menu-item" data-menu-item='{"title":"Sub Content 2"}'>
        <div class="ui-stack ui-stack-wrap ui-stack-align-center sortable-menu-item">
          <div class="ui-menu-handle"></div>
          <div class="ui-menu-item-title">Sub Content 2</div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="add-menu-item">
        <button class="ui-button button-add-item" type="button">Add menu item to Content 2</button>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item" data-menu-item='{"title":"Content 3"}'>
    <div class="ui-stack ui-stack-wrap ui-stack-align-center sortable-menu-item">
      <div class="ui-menu-handle"></div>
      <div class="ui-menu-item-title">Content 3</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="add-menu-item">
    <button class="ui-button button-add-item" type="button">Add menu item</button>
  </li>
</ol>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You mean to say u want to add button only once in each branch?

Comment: Yes, once at the bottom of each branch.

Comment: Confuse.. can u elaborate?

Comment: @PrashantTapase I thought the question was quite straightforward. For now, all I am trying to do is iterate over each branch in the tree when an item is sorted.

Comment: Hi, I don't see any element with class `ui-menu-item-branch` in the HTML..?

Comment: It gets created by the nested sortable plugin. Have a look at the DOM elements in the demo.

Comment: Please share the generated HTML, so we can find why the selector doesn't match...
Edit: nvm, didn't notice snippet is runnable

Comment: @TJ - Here's the created elements if it helps: https://pastebin.com/SjHQNkLm

Comment: @AsaCarter Thanks, I noticed you have a working snipped. I'm clicking the buttons and it is adding an item at the bottom as (I) expect. What is the expected behavior/how can I break the demo snippet?

Comment: @TJ, when an item is sorted (the blue dot is the drag handle), you will see some output in the console. It should iterate over the tree. You'll see that it's not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand you want something like the below snippet.
I used this selector: `var $branches = $el.parents('li.ui-menu-item-branch').not(':has( > ol li.add-menu-item)');`
Instead of recursion, jQuery does that for us.

```js
function addButton($el) {
  var tpl = '<li class="add-menu-item"><button class="ui-button button-add-item" type="button">Add menu item</button></li>';

  var $branches = $el.parents('li.ui-menu-item-branch').not(':has( > ol li.add-menu-item)');
  $branches.each(function(i, el) {
    $(el).find('> ol').append(tpl);
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sortable').nestedSortable({
    handle: '.ui-menu-handle',
    placeholder: 'ui-menu-placeholder',
    items: 'li:not(.add-menu-item)',
    toleranceElement: '> div',
    branchClass: 'ui-menu-item-branch',
    leafClass: 'ui-menu-item-leaf',
    collapsedClass: 'ui-menu-item-collapsed',
    expandedClass: 'ui-menu-item-expanded',
    errorClass: 'ui-menu-item-invalid',
    isTree: true,
    distance: 0,
    maxLevels: 3,
    isAllowed: function(placeholder, placeholderParent, currentItem) {
      if (placeholder.prev().hasClass('add-menu-item')) {
        return false;
      }
      if (placeholderParent && placeholderParent.hasClass('add-menu-item')) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    },
    relocate: function(event, currentItem) {
      var target = $(event.target);
      console.log('relocate', currentItem);
      addButton(currentItem.item);
    }
  });

  $('.sortable').on('click', '.button-add-item', function(e) {
    var el = $(this);
    var tpl = '<li class="ui-menu-item"><div class="ui-stack ui-stack-wrap ui-stack-align-center sortable-menu-item"><div class="ui-menu-handle ui-sortable-handle"></div><div class="ui-menu-item-title">Sub Content 2</div></div></li>';
    $(tpl).insertBefore(el);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.ui-stack {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: -1.6rem;
  margin-left: -1.6rem;
}

.ui-stack>* {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin-top: 1.6rem;
  margin-left: 1.6rem;
}

.ui-stack-wrap {
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.ui-stack-center {
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.ui-stack-align-center {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.ui-stack-vertical {
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.ui-stack-item {
  min-width: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.ui-stack-item-fill {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.ui-card-section.ui-navigation {
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.ui-navigation ol {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.ui-navigation li {
  padding: 0;
}

.ui-navigation ol ol {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.ui-navigation ol ol .sortable-menu-item,
.ui-navigation ol ol .button-add-item {
  border-left: 1px solid #dfe3e8;
}

.sortable-menu-item {
  padding: 10px;
  background: white;
  border-top: 1px solid #dfe3e8;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #dfe3e8;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #dfe3e8;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.ui-menu-handle {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #5c6ac4;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
}

.ui-menu-placeholder {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #5c6ac4;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.ui-menu-placeholder:before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #5c6ac4;
  top: -4px;
  left: -9px;
  content: "";
}

.ui-menu-placeholder.ui-menu-item-invalid,
.ui-menu-placeholder.ui-menu-item-invalid:before {
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-color: #bbb;
}

.ui-menu-item-title {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0.8rem;
}

.button-add-item {
  width: 100%;
  background: #f4f5fa;
  color: #5c6ac4;
  text-align: left;
  -webkit-transition: none;
  transition: none;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #dfe3e8;
  border-color: #dfe3e8;
  border-radius: 0;
  line-height: 34px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.button-add-item:hover {
  border-color: #5c6ac4;
  background: #5c6ac4;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nestedSortable/2.0.0/jquery.mjs.nestedSortable.js"></script>

  <head>

    <body>
      <div class="ui-navigation">
        <ol class="sortable">
          <li class="ui-menu-item" data-menu-item='{"title":"Content 1"}'>
            <div class="ui-stack ui-stack-wrap ui-stack-align-center sortable-menu-item">
              <div class="ui-menu-handle"></div>
              <div class="ui-menu-item-title">Content 1</div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="ui-menu-item" data-menu-item='{"title":"Content 2"}'>
            <div class="ui-stack ui-stack-wrap ui-stack-align-center sortable-menu-item">
              <div class="ui-menu-handle"></div>
              <div class="ui-menu-item-title">Content 2</div>
            </div>
            <ol>
              <li class="ui-menu-item" data-menu-item='{"title":"Sub Content 1"}'>
                <div class="ui-stack ui-stack-wrap ui-stack-align-center sortable-menu-item">
                  <div class="ui-menu-handle"></div>
                  <div class="ui-menu-item-title">Sub Content 1</div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="ui-menu-item" data-menu-item='{"title":"Sub Content 2"}'>
                <div class="ui-stack ui-stack-wrap ui-stack-align-center sortable-menu-item">
                  <div class="ui-menu-handle"></div>
                  <div class="ui-menu-item-title">Sub Content 2</div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="add-menu-item">
                <button class="ui-button button-add-item" type="button">Add menu item to Content 2</button>
              </li>
            </ol>
          </li>
          <li class="ui-menu-item" data-menu-item='{"title":"Content 3"}'>
            <div class="ui-stack ui-stack-wrap ui-stack-align-center sortable-menu-item">
              <div class="ui-menu-handle"></div>
              <div class="ui-menu-item-title">Content 3</div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="add-menu-item">
            <button class="ui-button button-add-item" type="button">Add menu item</button>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for. Ah `.parents()` is a selector I've never used before